# Spring Cloud config server - Sharing properties (for Group of related services)

Tags: spring-cloud-config, spring-cloud-config-server, spring-cloud-config-client

In our organization, we have over 100 micro services developed, and they are grouped into multiple business specific RAILS, such as ONLINE, Mobile, Payment, etc.

AS of now we have common properties, namely application.json, and also service specific properties, say mobiletransactions-it2.json, mobiletransactions-dev2.json, etc.

Newly we received a requirement, to use RAIL specific common properties, in addition to global application.json

So, we need to use RAIL specific properties, say Mobile-dev.json/Mobile.json that can be made available to all the services under Mobile RAILS, say mobileservice1-dev1, mobileservice2-dev, mobileservice1-it1, etc.

Can we have Mobile.json in addition to application.json for all the services under Mobile.

Any guidance would be helpful, thanks Arul